# I have unlocked the booloader for my xperia arc s running ICS 4.0.4 and would like to flash a custom ROM.?

Tags: root-access

I have unlocked the booloader for my xperia arc s running ICS 4.0.4 and would like to flash a custom ROM. I would like to know if i need to root and flash same kernal ? and also need to install the CWM recovery ? or is is fine to flash custom ROM right away?
please be specific with your answers !

Answer (score -1):

Don't even try to install any custom ROM or kernel without first flashing ClockworkMod. Also, I would suggest CyanogenMod, but that may not be compatible with your device. Check here: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Devices

Comment: This site expects self-sufficient answers. Please add the relevant info from the link. Also, *Don't even try to install any custom ROM or kernel without first flashing ClockworkMod.* -- do mention the reasoning for it.

Comment: Please be specific about wht you are sayin?

Comment: This hopefully should be the correct custom ROM for your device:

Comment: http://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/jenkins/5933/cm-9.0.0-nozomi.zip